# SQLite browser that reloads data on-the-fly

Tags: windows, gratis, sqlite, database-browser

There are many SQLite browsers out there, but for all of those I have tried, you don't see when data is modified by an external program. To make sure you are watching the most recent data, you have to press a refresh button, or even reopen the file.

My dream SQLite browser would either reload data every 5 seconds, or even better, watch the filesystem and detect when the database file has been modified, or anything similar to make sure I am always seeing the latest data.

Requirements:

- Never show out-of-date data for more than a few seconds.
- Free
- Run on Windows, bonus for Linux and Mac.